# Find if value in list has any value - 1 or value + 1 in list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list:

```
my_list = [8, 6, 2, 1, 9]
```

I want to know what values (or how many of them) in `my_list` that doesn't have any "neighbor integers" in the entire list. What I have come up with is this ugly loop.

```
for value in set(my_list):  # Using set() to remove duplicates to speed up loop
    if not value - 1 in my_list and not value + 1 in my_list:
        print(value)
```

The output here is only the integer 6 since there is no 5 or 7 in the list.

Is there any more elegant solution, that might also be faster?

Comment: `value - 1 in my_list` has O(n) time complexity. Consider converting `my_list` to a `set` to do it in O(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list comprehension way of doing this (this method should be the fastest among answers) -

```
mylist = set(my_list)

[i for i in my_list if i-1 not in my_list and i+1 not in my_list]
```

```
[ 6, 11, 15, 33]
```

---

Another method: Here is something you can do using NumPy in a vectorized manner.

```
import numpy as np
my_list = np.array([8, 6, 2, 1, 9, 11, 15, 33, 21, 22])

my_list[np.all(np.abs(my_list[:,None] - my_list)!=1, axis=1)]
```

```
array([ 6, 11, 15, 33])
```

To explain -

1. First you calculate the absolute difference between all elements of the list and itself utilizing the broadcasting capabilities of numpy. Basically, you get a pairwise difference matrix here.
2. You find which of the rows has any value ==1 and ignore those rows. These are the rows which have at least one other element where difference ==1 (neighbors)
3. You simply boolean index the original array.

Do run each of the wrapped NumPy functions to see what's happening.

Comment: Thank you, will try this and see if it gets any better! :)

Comment: This was actually the same or even a bit slower than my original for loop. Maybe it is because my list is maximum of 8 elements, and that I have to use len(list_comprehension). But, since this is a nice solution that I like, I will accpet this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is O(n^2).

You were on the right path converting the list to a set, but did not take full advantage of the created set (O(1) lookup).

This is O(n):

```
data_set = set(my_list)
for value in data_set:
    if value - 1 not in data_set and value + 1 not in data_set:
        print(value)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit long solution

```
def n(l):
neighbours = []
for i, v in enumerate(l):
    for v1 in l[i+1:]:
        if abs(v1-v) == 1:
            if v not in neighbours:
                neighbours.append(v)
            if v1 not in neighbours:
                neighbours.append(v1)
return neighbours
```

Comment: I did mention that on my answer.